# C# How can i update some column datetime in datagridview to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, updates

i need update some column in datagridview to database. but don't update to database.

step one: i select datetime from datetimepicker.

step two: show datetime on datagridview.

step tree: i need update/edit on datagridview to database.

**Display on Datagridview.**

```
EmpNo     fName     ChkDate     ChkIn   ChkOut
00001     Al        01/10/2012  08:02   17:04
00002     Bik       01/10/2012  07:43   18:35
```

i need update fields "ChkIn" to database.

**Code**

```
SqlConnection Conn;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter da;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


string appConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connDB"].ConnectionString;

int i;

    for (i = 1; i < dgvShow.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dgvShow.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(appConn);
            string sql = "UPDATE [WebSP].[dbo].[filesTA]"
            + "SET [filesTA].ChkIn = replace(convert(nvarchar(10),'" + dgvShow.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "',102),'.',':')"
            + "FROM [WebSP].[dbo].[filesTA]"
            + "WHERE [filesTA].ChkDate = '" + dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and [filesTA].EmpNo = '" + dgvShow.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "'";

            da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, Conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            Conn.Close();

            dgvShow.DataSource = ds;
            da.Update(ds);
        }
    }
```

Error: Update unable to find TableMapping['Table'] or DataTable 'Table'.

**I try other code:**

```
Conn = new SqlConnection();
            if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                Conn.Close();
            }
            Conn.ConnectionString = appConn;
            Conn.Open();

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [filesTA]", appConn);
            adapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [WebSP].[dbo].[filesTA]"
            + "SET [filesTA].ChkIn = replace(convert(nvarchar(10),@cIn,102),'.',':')"
            + "FROM [WebSP].[dbo].[filesTA]"
            + "WHERE [filesTA].ChkDate = @cDate and [filesTA].EmpNo = @eNo", Conn);

            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@cIn", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10, "ChkIn");
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@cDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10, "ChkDate");
            adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@eNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10, "EmpNo");

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);

            dgvShow.DataSource = ds;
            adapter.Update(ds);
```

this code not save to database.

## Thanks for your time. :D

**Type Database:**

ChkIn and ChkDate Type DateTime,EmpNo Type NUMERIC

**I try**

```
int i;
            for (i = 1; i < dgvShow.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dgvShow.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    using (Conn = new SqlConnection(appConn))
                    {
                        Conn.Open();

                        string sql = "UPDATE [WebSP].[dbo].[filesTA]" +
                                     "SET [filesTA].ChkIn = replace(convert(nvarchar(10),@cIn,102),'.',':')" +
                                     "FROM [WebSP].[dbo].[filesTA]" +
                                     "WHERE [filesTA].ChkDate = @cDate and [filesTA].EmpNo = @eNo";
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Conn);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@cIn", SqlDbType.DateTime, 10, "ChkIn").Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dgvShow.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value).ToString();
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@cDate", SqlDbType.DateTime, 10, "ChkDate").Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker.Value.ToString()).ToString();
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@eNo", SqlDbType.Decimal, 10, "EmpNo").Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvShow.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value).ToString();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }



                }
            }
```

Error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. T__T

Comment: Please show the value of sql string while you are compiling it

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get rid of the SqlDataAdapter using directly a SqlCommand

```
Using(Conn = new SqlConnection(appConn))
{
    Conn.Open();

    string sql = "UPDATE [WebSP].[dbo].[filesTA] " + 
                 "SET [filesTA].ChkIn = replace(convert(nvarchar(10),@cIn,102),'.',':') " + 
                 "FROM [WebSP].[dbo].[filesTA] " +
                 "WHERE [filesTA].ChkDate = @cDate and [filesTA].EmpNo = @eNo";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@cIn", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10, "ChkIn").Value = 
                               dgvShow.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@cDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10, "ChkDate").Value = 
                                 dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") ;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@eNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10, "EmpNo").Value = 
                                 dgvShow.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value ;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Of course, when using parameters, we need to set their values before running the command.

However I really don't understand well the code to update the ChkIn field. That field (according to the Parameter type) is a nvarchar, then why don't you try to format your @cIn value directly in code and avoid the use of Sql Server Replace and Convert functions? Also the **102** is a [**Date Style**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). It is used to format Date expressions as strings with the `yy.mm.dddd` pattern, but you have a string that contains only time info.

For example

**After your last edit - changed to this**

```
DateTime chkIN = Convert.ToDateTime(dgvShow.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
DateTime chkDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
decimal empNo = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvShow.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value) ;


cmd.Parameters.Add("@cIn", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = chkIN;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@cDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = chkDate;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@eNo", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = empNo;
```

Also the syntax used in query could be the source of other problems, but I need to see your connection string.

Comment: i try error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (i'm edit topic look on TOP)

Comment: Answer updated. You specify now a different type for your columns in database. Now pass two datetime and a decimal. Do not try to convert everything to strings.